# not well-formed in firefox when parsing XML using jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, firefox

The following code writes a warning in Firefox console,  not in Chrome. 
In both cases, the result is correct.

```
 $('status', $.parseXML("<root><status>1</status></root>")).text()
```

I just like to understand what is wrong. Any suggestion?

Comment: What does the warnig say?

Comment: it says 'mal formé' ('not well formed')

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

At beginning of your XML.

Comment: $('status', $.parseXML("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><root><status>1</status></root>")).text()
makes no differents, still 'not well formed'